# Can we place "all" after the noun?

Tags: difference, adverbs

> All the field intensities vanish.

Rephrase sentence:

> The field intensities all vanish.

Are they both grammatical and imply the same thing?

Comment: _Are they both grammatical and imply the same thing?_ Yes.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Yes.

They are both grammatically correct and mean fundamentally the same thing, although you'd probably find the latter "flows" better in spoken language.